# Loading different statics depending of the render in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, static

In my project i have two parts `landing` and `app`. Landing its showed when you are not logged and app is when you are logged. Both on the main route (http://localhost:3000/)

Both are independient so i would like to have to directories of statics

`- static/
-- landing/
--- css/
--- js/
-- app/
--- css/
--- js/`

Is possible load `static/landing/` as `http://localhost:3000/static/css/` when the user is not logged and `static/app/` when the user is logged?

Comment: How you detect in your code that user is logged in or not? Please explain so based on that we can suggest that

Comment: Using `express-session` and `passport` modules. Passport has a method called isAuthenticated()

Answer (score -1):

To detect if a user is logged in or not, you'll want to add a property to the `req.session` object. When your user is successfully logged in, set a flag (for example):

```
req.session.logged_in = true;
```

To then check if the user is logged in or not:

```
var sesssion = req.session
if (session && session.logged_in) {
    // Show app
    res.render('app/index');
} else {
    // Show landing
    res.render('landing/index');
}
```